# Construction of vector bundles of relativistic fields by Mackey's method of induced representation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, differential-geometry, field-theory, representation-theory

I recently stumbled on [Sternberg's book on group theory and physics](https://www.amazon.de/Group-Theory-Physics-S-Sternberg/dp/0521558859). The ideas expressed in the book are really great, but the detailed reasoning is very hard to follow, I find. I am kind of stuck with his derivation of relativistic wave equations (Section 3.9 and 4.9). I hope that some of you may help me clarify this.

I think I do understand the construction of the vector bundle of a relativistic field. So one starts with the dual space $N^*$, which is the momentum space (the character space of the translation group $N=\mathbb{R}^4$). One lets the Lorentz group (as part of the Poincare group) acts on this space, which breaks it into different orbits. Then one picks up an orbit (or also called a mass shell), say $m^2=p_0^2-\vec{p}^2$. On this mass shell one picks a point, say $(m,0,0,0)$. Now one identifies the isotropy subgroup of this point $(m,0,0,0)$, which for positive mass and positive energy is isomorphic to $SU(2)$. Now all the irreducible representations of $SU(2)$ are known, and one can construct a vector bundle on which the Pointcare group acts irreducibly.

Let us assume that we are interested in $s=\frac{1}{2}$ representation of $SU(2)$. The whole vector bundle together with the action of the Poincare group is well-defined (by the method of induced representation, Section 3.3, 3.4). Each fibre over $\vec{p}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2$, however in each fibre there is no preferred basis. Even if at $(m,\vec{0})$ we fix a basis, the basis at some other point $(p_0,\vec{p})$ is not identified in his construction of induced representation. Without the basis, it is not possible to construct the spinor wave function, say $\psi^{\sigma} (\vec{p})$. In other words, at each point of the mass shell, one can pick an arbitrary basis, and $\psi^{\sigma} (\vec{p})$ would be different. But in physics what we really want is a way to fix the basis for spin component 'everywhere' over the space. It is unclear to me how such a global choice comes out of this construction. (Sternberg does argue some embedding into the the bundle into the trivial bundle, but I still cannot follow the arguments there. It seems to me that he works backwards from the relativistic equations.)

(I also know the construction in Wu-ki Tung's Group theory in Physics, which is based on the representations of Lie algebra. But the language in the book seems somehow too imprecise for me to really understand it.)

Any guides or comments are gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how people choose a basis of gamma matrices for the Clifford algebra?  There are many possible choices, and it's something that often makes comparing different QFT text books difficult.

Comment: @user2309840 No, it isn't. My question was Wigner's derivation of relativistic wave equations: finding the irreducible representation of the Poincare invariance, one is supposed to be able to derive the field bundle for eletromagnetic system (tangent bundle), the spinor bundle (embedded in the Clifford bundle, if I understand correctly). I get the construction of the bundles, but cannot identify them with the tangent bundle and the Clifford bundle. Or one can put it this way: from the construction, one can choose gamma at different spacetime points differently (a bit like gauge invariance)

Comment: For the information: I finally find the answer in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0303031.pdf (Sec. 2.2). So the arbitrariness in the choice of local basis is indeed there. And one indeed has to try a special choice to derive the relativistic equations.